# How do I figure out my Google OpenID URL?

Tags: google-account, openid

I'm trying to log in to the CakePHP website using Open ID:
http://ask.cakephp.org/users/login

The most correct looking URL I've found is:
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id

..but I can't properly determine what I'm supposed to enter for my open ID, as it rejects everything that I try putting in.

Is the cake site just broken, or do I have the wrong URL?

Comment: 2016 update: Some apps that rely on deprecated OpenID2 will no longer work with a Google OpenID provider at all. See: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenID2Migration

Answer (score 35, accepted):

On most sites you can use your Google profile link when logging in to OpenID. E.g. `http://www.google.com/profiles/your.name.here`

Before Google profile OpenID support you had to use `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id`

You can read more about it at Jeff Atwood blog post: [Google Offers Named OpenIDs](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/google-offers-named-openids/).

**However, it appears, that at [ask.cakephp.org](http://ask.cakephp.org/users/login) Google profile URLs are not working.** As noted by Greg, if you are logged in to your google account, **`google.com`** will work as OpenID url there.

Comment: It isn't working, even though I am logged in to my google account.  "Returned identity did not match claimed identity" =/

Comment: Can you login to any other site using your Google OpenID? I can log in to ask.cakephp.org with `google.com` as well as with `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id`. Maybe there is an issues with your Google OpenID.

Comment: Yup, that's how I authenticate to StackOverflow/etc.  I also had a friend try it; didn't work for them either.

Answer (score 15):

My original solution seems to not be as useful any more because they have changed the page.
I have it at the end of the post just for reference

## New Solution 2014-08-08

1. Goto https://www.google.com/settings
2. Sign in with your account

   - If you have a google+ account then you should have links for:

     1. Add photo;
     2. Edit profile; and
     3. View profile.
3. If you copy the address for one of those it will be like

   - `https://plus.google.com/{YOUR_PROFILE_NUMBER}/{EXTRA STUFF}`
4. Remove the **/{EXTRA_STUFF}** and that can be used as your OpenID

   - Thanks to [kevin kox](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/33947/kevin-cox) to also suggesting that you can replace plus.google.com with profiles.google.com as your OpenId, *though you don't need to*.

## Original Solution

None of the other answers worked for me. However, what did was following the below steps.

*NOTE: you should be able to skip some of the steps and go straight to the [privacy link](https://www.google.com/settings/privacy).*

1. Log into your account in Google
2. Click on the profile down arrow
3. Click the [Privacy Link](https://www.google.com/settings/privacy)
4. On the right will be the link to your Google Open ID URL

   - Mine was `https://plus.google.com/{RANDOM_NUMBER}`, where the random number is specific to my profile

Note that you might not get this unless you have a Google+ account.

Comment: The selected answer didn't work for me (http://www.google.com/profiles/your.name.here) but the URL found under the Privacy Link did.

Comment: it is some thing like https://plus.google.co/114818586844452309461

Comment: it seems not working for now

Comment: Lastest solution `https://plus.google.com/{YOUR_PROFILE_NUMBER}` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

To use the Google OpenID with Google Apps (in my case, a gmail business package, where my ID is NOT @gmail.com) it was REALLY hidden.

If you visit your account page ( eg https://www.google.com/settings/account ) and view-source, search for "https://profiles.google.com/"
There you will find the long mysterious number that is the URL for your OpenID.

Comment: The links don't work sometimes if you have a corp account which blocks it from having a +1 account.

Answer (score 5):

Google has cancelled OpenID URL logins, unfortunately, according to the [Google One Support](https://support.google.com/googleone) representative I spoke to today. (They provided chat ID 7-0404000030383 for future reference, though I assume only myself and authorized Google folks can access it.)

So none of the schemes provided in previous answers here (via your Google Profile, Google Plus, etc) work any more. They result in this message for me now on at least one OpenID relying site:

```
Sorry, that is not a valid OpenID. Ensure you have spelled your ID correctly.
```

Another open standard for authentication that seems relevant is [OpenID Connect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID_Connect), as described (for Google) here: [Google's OAuth 2.0 APIs can be used for both authentication and authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect)

Answer (score 4):

This is a little complicated.

First there is the "Google OpenID URL" or https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id.  This is useful when signing up or logging in as it will redirect to the proper URL.

You can also use your Google+ profile URL.  Go to https://plus.google.com and click "profile".  You will get a URL like `https://plus.google.com/112323959773786487818/posts`.  Remove the end to get `https://plus.google.com/112323959773786487818` and you can use this URL (I think this is the new recommended way now).

However, these all redirect to your true Google OpenID URL.  The URL is your Google Profile address.  This is your Google+ user ID after `https://profiles.google.com`.  For example, my OpenID URL is `https://profiles.google.com/112323959773786487818`.  This URL is useful when you are inputting your OpenID URL into an application without logging in.

Answer (score 1):

Just enter google.com (whomever is your Open ID provider)

EDIT:

Make sure you're logged in to Google (or whomever is your Open ID provider) before entering their address.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  I get "Returned identity did not match claimed identity".  Hence the whole suspicion of their site being broken.